# Python: Error when appending new item to a list in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe with three columns: **user_id** (str), **list_of_purchases** (list) and a binary column named **b**.

I would like to create a fourth column named **final_list** that follows the rules below:

- When **b** = 1, then **final_list** should be the concatenation of **list_of_purchases** and the item "Success". So for example, if **list_of_purchases** = ['item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3'] then **final_list** should be ['item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3','Success']
- When **b** = 0, then instead of "success", **final_list** should be ['item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3','Null']

I tried the following code but got the error:

```
df['final_list'] = np.where(
    df['b'] == 0,
    df['list_of_purchases'] + ['Null'],
    df['list_of_purchases'] + ['Success'])

TypeError: Cannot broadcast np.ndarray with operand of type <class 'list'>
```

I figured out how to do it using a for loop and checking every row in column **b**, but it is really ineficient and takes a long time.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What ius `df_paths`, and how does it relate to `df`?

Comment: Hi @Barmar! Sorry, the code was incorrect. There is no df_paths, only df. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feels like a nice use for a lambda, rather than defining a function, though both approaches work.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[1, [1,2,3]],
        [0, [4,5,6]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["b", "list_of_purchases"])

df["Output"] = df.apply( \
    lambda row : row["list_of_purchases"] + \
    ["Success" if row["b"] else "Null"], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Produces:

```
   b list_of_purchases              Output
0  1         [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3, Success]
1  0         [4, 5, 6]     [4, 5, 6, Null]
```

"Benefits" of using a lambda are (here) basically just that it avoids defining a function which you might not ever reuse.

If the function/logic is to be reused elsewhere then defining a function (and **not** using a lambda) might be exactly the right approach. If it's only used for this, and not reused, I'd probably go with the lambda.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. And yes, using lambda in this case is preferred since I won't need to reuse this function later on ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#create a function:
def lista(df):
    return [df['list_of_purchases'] + ['Null'] if df['b'] == 0 else df['list_of_purchases'] + ['Success']]

#use the function on every row of df:
df['final_list'] = df.apply(lista, axis=1)
```

from what I understand, pandas dataframes are not designed to store lists as their values, so super efficient solutions are not available

Comment: Because 0 can considered same as False, and 1 as True, `df['b'] == 0` is the same as just using `df['b']`, though you need to switch around the Null and Success cases, as the condition comes out the other way around.

Comment: Hi Adam! Thank you for contributing. I preferred using the lambda version of this solution since I won't need to reuse the function later on in the script. Nevertheless, thank you!